# Energy functions of linear PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I currently have some troubles generating suitable energy functions to satisfy the given PDEs, especially in the case of non-homogeneous Dirichlet condition. Would really appreciate if someone could help with the following problems:

(a) $-\ div(a{u}) + cu = f$ in $\omega$ where $a,c\in C^{0}(\bar{\omega})$, and they are discontinuous across a portion of the boundary called $\gamma$

$ \ \ \ \ \ u = g$ on $\gamma$

$\ \ \ \ \ \ a(\nabla u\cdot v) = 0$ on $\gamma$

(b) $\ -div(a{u}) + cu = f$ in $\omega$

$\ \ \ \ \ a(\nabla u\cdot v) + h(u-g) = k$ on $(\partial{\omega} - \gamma)$

**My attempt:** I tried guessing the energy function $I[u] = \int_{\omega} [\frac{1}{2}(a\nabla u\cdot \nabla u + cu^2) - fu] dx$. But then when I tried to compute the first variation $\frac{d}{d\epsilon} [I(u+\epsilon h)|_{\epsilon = 0}]$, I ended up with $\int_{\omega} h(\nabla u\cdot v + uc - f)$, which is not equivalent to the Euler-Lagrange function. Plus there is no term involving the boundary condition, which is weird. Due to these reasons, I think I messed up on defining the correct energy function $I[u]$. Could someone please help?

For the other part, I also tried $I[u] = \int_{\omega} [\frac{1}{2}(a\nabla u\cdot \nabla u + cu^2) - fu]dx - \int_{\gamma} [k-h(u-g)]u\ dx$. But the first variation of $I[u]$ also does not give me anything that resembles the original PDE. Could anyone please give me the correct energy function, as well as its corresponding first variation in this problem?

Comment: Nobody wants to help me with this difficult problem?

Comment: should the part (a) BC's be given on distinct subsets of $\partial\omega$?

Comment: @ellya: that's correct. But the original problem is only different by requiring $u=g$ on entire $\partial{w}$, while $\grad{u}\cdot v = 0$ on $\gamma$. Otherwise, what are the BCs you are thinking of?

Comment: it just seems as though two bcs are being imposed at once

Comment: Well, yes, that's the case. Why not though?

Comment: In general it's over imposed, what if $g$ doesn't satisfy the Neumann condition?

Comment: what would make more sense would be $u=g$ on $\gamma$, $a(\nabla u\cdot\nu)=0$ on $\partial\omega\setminus\overline{\gamma}$.

Comment: @ellya: but functions $a,\ c$ are discontinuous on $\gamma$. So we need the BCs in such a way to make the integrals of the weak form that contains functions $a,\ c$ makes sense.

Comment: I think I'm just lacking clarity here, also if $a,c\in C^0(\overline{\omega})$, how can they be discontinuous on the boundary, this contradicts the continuity assumption.

Comment: @ellya: that's the problem statement. I think what it means is $a,c$ are continuous on $\partial{w}\gamma$.

Comment: I believe, as it stands, the problem statement is incorrect.